# Confused at how max and min media queries work

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

So I understand the `(min-width: 1400px)` and `(max-width: 1400px)` are break points for when the CSS reaches those breakpoints it supposed to go back to its default sizing.

This is what I have done. I have my main CSS file that has its default sizing and another CSS file called query.css that controls the responsiveness of the web page.

This is how I have certain parts of both files to adjust accordingly

main CSS

```
.h1,.h2,.h3 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: Cinzel, sans-serif;
}

.nav-link {
  padding-left: 10rem !important;
}
```

query CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .h1,.h2,.h3 {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  .nav-link{
    padding-left: 5em !important;
  }

}
```

This is where it confuses me. The main CSS file settings are meant to be the main one, but the query CSS seems to overwrite the main CSS and it really messes up when I try and do responsive design.

I get that this `min-width:1400px` is meant to say if it goes from `2000px` down to `1400px` it must keep the `min-width:1400px`, but then what is the point of having the main CSS if the `min-width:1400px` just negates the main CSS file settings.

Its very frustrating working like this.

Answer (score 0):

> ... it must keep the min-width:1400px ...

That's not how min-width works with media queries.

The `min-width` rule effectively says "apply this block of CSS *if* the viewport is at least this wide", in this case at least 1400px. if the viewport width is less than 1400px then the CSS surrounded by the media query will not be applied and the styles defined in main.css will take precedence.

```css
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  /* CSS that is only applied if the viewport is >= 1400px */
}
```

Also, be careful about the order that the CSS files are included in the page. If query.css was included before then the media query it contains would always be over-ruled by the CSS in main.css.

It's a little more complicated than this when you take [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in to account, but you should get the general idea.

For more info, take a look at [the documentation for the media query min-width rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width).

Answer (score 0):

An important aspect of `media-queries` is structuring them correctly - especially if you're using a combination of `@media (min-width: x)` and `@media (max-width: x)`.

CSS is read from top to bottom - this means that the **last** property applied to your desired selector will take priority, as long as its valid. This means that a more "precise/accurate" `media-query` rule prop will **not** take priority over another, if the `media-query` is placed below the other and both of their rules are valid. This means you can't just throw in `media-queries` at random locations in your CSS-file, because the CSS is just going to be overwritten.

Note that this doesn't apply on more **specific** selectors, but in my personal preference, I don't like mixing the specificity on a selector across multiple `media-queries`.

Because of this, you should always make `media-query`-rules with:

> A **descending** pixel value if you're using `max-width`
>
> An **ascending** pixel value if you're using `min-width`
>
> **In this example**, the `min-width`-`media-queries` below the `max-width`-`media-queries`

This way, the first `media-query` will always take priority as long as its rules apply. When the second `media-query`'s rule apply, that will take priority instead and so on. Try dragging the screen size of this code snippet in full page and you'll see how this code structuring works.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 412px) {
  div {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  div {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  div {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 414px) {
  div {
    background-color: black;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 428px) {
  div {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  div {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  div {
    background-color: gray;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 820px) {
  div {
    background-color: limegreen;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 834px) {
  div {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 884px) {
  div {
    background-color: teal;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```